# Universal Property of Integral Closure

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to understand an exercise from Hartshorne's book, *Algebraic Geometry*, about normalization of an integral scheme. So, I'm reduced to prove the affine case and then glue. In dealing with this case, I did not know how to express the dual property for rings. Being specific, Let $A$ be an integral domain, and $\tilde A$ its integral closure in its total ring of quotients. I guess that the universal property enjoyed by $\tilde A$ is this:

> Given a ring $B$ integrally closed, and a ring homomorphism $f:A\longrightarrow B$, there is a unique ring homomorphism $\tilde f:\tilde A\longrightarrow B$, such that $\tilde f\iota=f$, where $\iota$ is the inclusion of $A$ in $\tilde A$.

As I mentioned, I don't know if this property is the right one, or if I have to put something more on the morphism $f$. I tried without success to show that in fact, $\tilde A$ has the property that I wrote. I guess I'm missing something.

I've looked in Matsumura's book and Eisenbud's book, but I did not find this formulation. I would be very grateful if someone can tell me what is the correct property, and in case I was correct, how to prove it.

Comment: I think you need $f$ to be injective. If you look at Exercise I, 3.17 of Hartshorne's book, there the universal property of normalization of the affine variety was given.

Comment: If $f$ is injective you can extend it to $f : \text{Frac}(A) \to \text{Frac}(B)$ thus to $f:\overline{A} \to \text{Frac}(B)$, and for any $a \in \overline{A}, f(a) \in \overline{B}$ because $a^d+\sum_{n=0}^{d-1} c_n a^n = 0, c_n \in A \implies f(a)^d+\sum_{n=0}^{d-1} f(c_n) f(a)^n = 0,f(c_n) \in B$. If $f$ is not injective, I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment by @Krish suggests, we need $f$ to be injective.

First, let me give you a counterexample, if $f$ is not injective:

Consider the normalization $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 5] \subset \mathbb Z[\frac{1+ \sqrt{5}}{2}]$ and the map $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z$, where $p$ is a prime number, that is still prime in $\mathbb Z[\frac{1+ \sqrt 5}{2}]$. In that case, there is no ring map from $\mathbb Z[\frac{1+ \sqrt 5}{2}]$ to $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ at all, in particular you cannot extend $f$.

---

If $f: A \to B$ is injective, you get a map of quotient fields and then it is trivial that the image of the restriction of this map to $\overline A$ is contained in $\overline B=B$. This gives you the desired map $\overline A \to B$.

Comment: Well, he said "$B$ is integrally closed". This suggests that $B$ is a domain. If $B$ is no domain one usually refers to this as normality and defines it via $S_2$ and $R_1$.

Comment: This probably a typo, the OP meant $B$ is an integral domain and $\overline{B}$ its integral closure ? Also for $f$ not injective, how would you check if $f$ extends to $\overline{A}$ ?

Comment: I meant looking at something in $\ker(f)$ to find if it extends or not. And your  counter-example is weird, did you mean $f : \mathbb{Z}[p \sqrt{5}] \to \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ with $p$ prime in $\mathbb Z[\frac{1+ \sqrt 5}{2}]$ (so the extension is $f : \mathbb Z[\frac{1+ \sqrt 5}{2}] \to \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1+ \sqrt 5}{2}] \cong \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$) ?